# Where to find updates for deprecated functions?

Tags: objective-c, ios4, xcode4

Xcode4 will tell you if a function is deprecated but does not provide any info on what to use as the latest update for that function.  What is the best way to find out the updated version of any deprecated function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I always search the documentation with the function name and get the new version of the old methods. It works all the time.

Comment: I just downloaded the iOS core library documentation.  However, all of my searches reference the Mac OS X 10.6 Core Library.  I'm searching 'initWithFrame'.  How do I get it to look in the iOS library?

Comment: There must be a search in content option were the Mac OS X is ticked. just check iOS library 4.2 or what ever and then your are good to go.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

There is a drop down(Doc Set) to select the libraries you want to search, in the Documentation window